# Find $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{e^{xy} -1}{ x^2 + y^2} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that the limit does not exits

Find $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{ x^2 + y^2} $

I tried finding the limit as f(x) approaches from x and y axes but I still get an indeterminate answer.

Comment: something error showing in your function

Comment: As you approach along the $x$ or $y$ axes, the function is identically zero (the numerator vanishes), so even though you get an indeterminate of $\frac{0}{0}$, the limit is $0$.

Comment: What about trying other trajectories to approach $(0,0)$? For instance, $y=x$, $y=2x$...

Answer (score 1):

When $y=0$ and $x\not=0$,
$$
f(x,y)=f(x,0)=\frac{e^{x\cdot 0}-1}{x^2+0^2}=\frac{e^0-1}{x^2}=\frac{1-1}{x^2}=\frac{0}{x^2}=0.
$$
Therefore, whenever $x\not=0$, and $(x,y)$ is on the $x$-axis, this function is identically zero.  Therefore, the limit as $x$ approaches zero is $0$.

Now, if you try the trajectory where $x=y$, then
$$
f(x,y)=f(x,x)=\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{2x^2}.
$$
As $x$ (and $y$) approach zero, you do get an indeterminate form, but a single application of l'Hopital's rule (or looking at the power series expansion) will show that this limit is not zero.

Comment: wouldn't l'hopital's rule turn the limit into 2xe^(x^2)/4x.Then applying it again would give you 4x^2(e^(x^2))/4 making the limit 0?

Comment: @michael Cancel your $x$'s to get $\frac{1}{2}e^{x^2}$.  Also, it looks like your second application of l'Hopital's rule forgot the product rule in the numerator.

Comment: More precisely, the derivative of $2xe^{x^2}$ is $2e^{x^2}+4x^2e^{x^2}$.